# Dynamic dimensional model per company in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, cube, dimensional-modeling

I'm designing system where each table supports dimensions. There are a couple of ways achieving it by using snowflake, star schemas. Unfortunately I don't see how I can apply any of this in my use case because:

- system is accessed by different companies and each company can have different dimensions meaning per table and they can set that by themselves. For example, company A wants dimensions: Warehouse, Category while Company B wants: Product, Location dimensions. Also dimension can be different per company and table. For example, Person and Agreement tables have different meanings of their dimensions.
- most of the time mostly up to 3 dimensions should be supported

Design #1:
Fact table Agreement

```
   Agreement table
     RecordId (reference id to particular table record)
     SalaryAmount
     ClientId
     DimensionValue1 (for company A it can be gender, for company B it can mean warehouse location)
     DimensionValue2
     DimensionValue3
```

- Each table has 3 columns for each dimension value to be inserted.
- Every table has column ClientId which tells for which company record belongs to
- when dimension is aggregated title of each dimension is loaded from settings table.

Design #2:

- Each table has no reference to dimension but instead we could have Dimension table

  ```
   Dimension table
     RecordId (reference id to particular table record)
     Value
     ClientId
     Type (what kind of dimension type it is: Category, Product, Warehouse and so on.)
  ```

That way I could have many dimensions that would be saved in one table. Unfortunately, I am afraid of this design performance (actually for both of them).
How valid are these designs when there are not so much of data (up to 300k).

Comment: Dimension are one thing, but how are you planning on storing the data belonging to them? More generic columns?

Comment: @siggemannen yes, basically adding three more columns for existing tables that needs them. Then I am doing aggregate query by grouping them in order to achieve some metric.

Comment: It appears that each company requires a fundamentally different design. If this is the case, I'm not sure what benefit you think there is in trying to force them into a single, common design? Why not just build what each company requires? That would almost certainly be easier than trying to build and maintain what you are describing - or am I missing something?

Comment: Though if what you are describing is a standard model but companies only see a subset of that model then that could easily be achieved using views